# MATLAB: Find indices/count of specific rgb pixel values in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm using matlab to get counts of specific pixel values in an image.

Images are RGBA <512x512x4 uint8> when read into matlab (although we can disregard the alpha channel).

Other than;

```
[width, height, depth] = size(im);

for x = 1 : width;
    for y = 1: height;

        r = im(x,y,1);
        g = im(x,y,2);
        b = im(x,y,3);

        ...

    end
end
```

Is there a way I can do this using matrix operations? Something along the lines of:

```
X = find(im(:,:,1) == 255 && im(:,:,2) == 255 && im(:,:,3) == 255);
count = length(X);
% Count being the number of pixels with RGB value (255,255,255) in the image.
```

I'm guessing there's more than a few ways to do this (looking at intersect, unique functions) but I'm not clever enough with matlab to do this yet. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. Something like this

```
count = sum(im(:, :, 1) == 255 & im(:, :, 2) == 255 & im(:, :, 3) == 255);
```

will give you the count of such pixels. Replace `sum` with `find` to get the indices of those pixels if you need that.

Comment: Based on this I used:

count = length(find(im(:,:,1) == 255 & im(:,:,2) == 255 & im(:,:,3) == 255) == 1);

which is exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Well, `length` of `find` is fine - but it'll be more expensive. Using `sum` is straightforward, does exactly the same thing, and is faster. Of course you will need `find` if you want the indices.

Comment: Ah, I got it working with sum using: `R = sum(sum(im(:,:,1) == 0 & im(:,:,2) == 0 & im(:,:,3) == 0));` for the one-liner. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with many ways.
One way is this. 
Let's say your image is HxWx3
create a HxW table with the r value you want to search for, one HxW for the g and one for the blue. You can combine all thos tables as dimensions in a HxWx3 table F. 
Substract F from im and use the find() function to get the indexes of zeroed values.

```
F(:,:,1)=R*ones(H,W); F(:,:,2)=G*ones(H,W); F(:,:,3)=B*ones(H,W);
```

then if you do im-F you get zeroes on the wanted positions

```
d=F-im;    [r,c]=find((d(:,:,1))==0)
```

That way you can input also a threshold of how close you want the rgb set to be.

Comment: This was the route I was trying to take (logical masks) but couldn't get working. Gotta give the accepted answer to Ansari for conciseness though, but thanks! :)