# Percentage of green, yellow and red in an image matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors

[image]

Image is hard to click, so [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CwoR.jpg).

I have an image having green, yellow and red color as shown above and would like to calculate percentage of these areas in the 'true color' image format 'jpg 'pic. The pic I am assuming will have only these three colors. Please guide me as to how to do it?

Comment: The same way you calculate any percentage, divide the subset by the total...

Comment: What is your problem doing so? Are you able [to count the pixels of each colour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723943/matlab-find-indices-count-of-specific-rgb-pixel-values-in-image)?

Comment: @Daniel how do I count the value of each color separately ? It's represented in 3 planes, so I am not sure exactly how? I am used to working on greyscale images but not colors..so I have no idea unfortunately!

Comment: Read the linked question!

Comment: @Daniel I'm flagging that question as duplicate.  The OP just has to make one more step and calculate the percentage.

Comment: be aware of colour artefacts due to jpg compression. so counting values that equal 255 might be insufficient!

Comment: @Daniel i got it!! i am able to successfully calculate it using the link you shared! thanks a million :) n thx for marking it duplicate..as it is based on that.

Comment: @Piglet thanks for comment..yes i considered your point in calculation..really needed to be considered :)